# Pandas: "Left Join" not working correctly

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to apply left join to the two dataframe shown below.

```
      outlier   day season
0      11556.0   0      1
==========================================
    date  bikeid       date2
0      1   16736  2016-06-06
1      1   16218  2016-06-13
2      1   15254  2016-06-20
3      1   16327  2016-06-27
4      1   17745  2016-07-04
5      1   16975  2016-07-11
6      1   17705  2016-07-18
7      1   16792  2016-07-25
8      1   18540  2016-08-01
9      1   17212  2016-08-08
10     1   11556  2016-08-15
11     1   17694  2016-08-22
12     1   14936  2016-08-29
```

outliers = pd.merge(outliers, sum_Day, how = 'left', left_on = ['outlier'], right_on = ['bikeid'])

outliers = outliers.dropna(axis=1, how='any')

```
  trip_outlier day season
0      11556.0   0      1
```

As shown after above applying left join i dropped all the NaN rows which gives the result above. However the desired results should be as shown below

```
  trip_outlier day season     date2
0      11556.0   0      1   2016-08-15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `dtype` of `outlier` column in `outliers` is float. Need same `dtypes` in both joined columns.

Check it by:

```
print (outliers['outlier'].dtype)
print (sum_Day['bikeid'].dtype)
```

So use `astype` for convert:

```
outliers['outlier'] = outliers['outlier'].astype(int)
#if not int
#sum_Day['bikeid'] = sum_Day['bikeid'].astype(int)
```

EDIT:

If some `NaN`s in `outlier` column is not possible convert to `int`, first is necessary remove `NaN`s:

```
outliers = outliers.dropna('outlier')
outliers['outlier'] = outliers['outlier'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks! it was the datatype causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the desired result would be using the below code:

```
outliers = outliers.merge(sum_Day.rename(columns={'bikeid': 'outlier'}), on = 'outlier', \
how = 'left')
```